# How to download multiple files simultaneously in WP8.1 WinRT using Background Downloader

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on an app in WP8.1 where i need to download multiple files at the same time but i am attempting only one download at a time.
 Can anybody help me how to achieve this to download multiple files simultaneously. Not in group.

Thanks

Comment: No sorry. And you know why? Because you didn't showed what you have tried so far, you just came by and ask for  solution. [Unacceptable](https://importantshock.files.wordpress.com/2008/08/unacceptable.png?w=455&h=562).

Answer (score -1):

Although it won't be good to do it if you have too many files, you can try creating a thread for every file.

```
foreach(var fileAddress in fileAddressList)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
            //Download code here
    });
}
```

**Again, do not do it if you have too many files!** Its ok if the files are small, but huge files and too many threads wont be a wise thing to do.